# API endpoint for manually launching a job in rancher v 2.6.8

Tags: kubernetes, endpoint, rancher

I am trying to find the API endpoints for manually triggering the cronjobs/pods for an application on rancher via a script instead of clicking the "run now" button in the edit config option:

[image: edit config]

I get some endpoints but I am not sure which one to get as I can't see any for workloads. Any help or lead would be appreciated.

Comment: seems that's discouraged/discontinued https://forums.rancher.com/t/api-view-in-rancher-2-6/36819/2 even though they plan _something_  https://github.com/rancher/rancher-docs/issues/583

Answer (score 1):

You can find the API Endpoint by following the Instructions [here](https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/pages-for-subheaders/about-the-api#capturing-rancher-api-calls).

For CronJobs I get a HTTPS POST to the batch.jobs API Endpoint like (Rancher v2.7.9):

```
curl 'https://<FQDN-Rancher>/k8s/clusters/<cluster-ID>/v1/batch.jobs/default' -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Cookie: R_SESS=<Bearer-Token-Rancher>' --data-raw '{"type":"batch.job","kind":"Job","metadata":{"creationTimestamp":null,"namespace":"default","name":"hello-job","ownerReferences":[{"apiVersion":"batch/v1","controller":true,"kind":"CronJob","name":"hello","uid":"6a4ff3a1-fd3a-4614-b4db-631a648c4f47"}]},"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"creationTimestamp":null},"spec":{"containers":[{"command":["/bin/sh","-c","date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster"],"image":"busybox:1.28","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","name":"hello","resources":{},"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File"}],"dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst","restartPolicy":"OnFailure","schedulerName":"default-scheduler","securityContext":{},"terminationGracePeriodSeconds":30}}}}'
```

This HTTPS POST request is stripped down a bit to show only (in my understanding) the necessary data.

<s>A bit weird that it does not use `https://<FQDN-Rancher>/v3` or `https://<FQDN-Rancher>/v1`.</s>

I now worked more with the Rancher API and found out that it is indeed NOT werid that it does use `https://<FQDN-Rancher>/k8s/clusters/<cluster-ID>/`:

`https://<FQDN-Rancher>/k8s/clusters/<cluster-ID>/` exposes the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) of the desired Cluster with the `<cluster-ID>`.

`https://<FQDN-Rancher>/v1` is for all Resources related to the Rancher own local Cluster. So all Resources which are found in the Navigation Sidebar in the local cluster Tab.

`https://<FQDN-Rancher>/v3` is for all Resources which are "Rancher-Global".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able list cronjobs via kubectl and then trigger a run for it check docs for more details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/)

```
kubectl get cronjob
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/name
```